# Calculating Probabilities and Using Binomial Distribution

Tags: random-variables, binomial-distribution, bayes-theorem

> A recent survey of residents in Texas concluded that 55% of Austin city residents and 46% of Houston city residents broke a bone at some point during their childhood.

> a. Let’s say Austin has 5200 residents, and Houston has 4500. You independently choose two residents with replacement from the combined 9700 and learn that both of them broke a bone as a child. What’s the probability that the two residents live in different cities?

For this part, I'm calculating the probability of getting one person w/ broken bone from each city (0.253), divided by the probability that any two residents who broke their bone are chosen (0.2583). However, I realized that I may be able to format this as a Bayes theorem problem instead. Which way would be correct, and if using Bayes, how would I get the right terms?

> b. You interview 500 Houston residents, sampled independently with replacement. What’s the approximate probability that more than 220 of them broke a bone as a child?

I calculated this as a Bin(500, 0.46) modeled as a Normal distribution, and calculated that P(X > 220) = 0.8152. However, this probability seems off to me.

Comment: For part (a), Bayes Theorem is the way to go.  Let $E_1$ denote the combined events of choosing two people, both from Austin, and both having their bones broken.  Let $E_2$ denote the analogous events re Houston.  Let $E_3$ denote the somewhat similar events that the 1st person is from Austin, and the 2nd person is from Houston.  Let $E_4$ denote the reverse event of Houston, then Austin.  Then, the desired computation is $$\frac{p(E_3) + p(E_4)}{p(E_1) + p(E_2) + p(E_3) + p(E_4)}.$$

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you, but how would I get p(E3) and p(E4)?

Comment: $p(E_3)$ computed as probability that 1st person is from Austin times conditional probability that person's arm broken times conditional probability that 2nd person from Houston times conditional probability that 2nd person's arm broken.  Given two events $T_1$ and $T_2$, the  phrase *conditional probability* (of event $T_2$, given event $T_1$) represents the probability of event $T_2$ occurring under the **narrow assumption** that event $T_1$ has occurred.

Comment: **Warning** : problem composer's intent unclear.  From the premise, Austin contains $5200$ people, of which exactly $2860$ have suffered a break.  If both people come from Austin, are you to assume that the probability of the 2nd person's arm having been broken is $(0.55)$ or $~\displaystyle \frac{2859}{5199}.$  The problem composer probably intends the former assumption, while the latter assumption is technically more accurate.